# How to fix django inconsistent date fields?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model that has attribute `models.DateField(db_index=True)`

i insert `datetime.strptime("2019-07-08", "%Y-%m-%d")` into it.

Now, when I `get()` on it I get:  `datetime.date(2019, 7, 1)` as opposed to `datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0)`

Why is it inconsistent? :(

Comment: You need to use ```models.DateTimeField``` instead of ```models.DateField```.

Comment: @cagrias thanks! I'm a bit hesistant about modifying migrations -- is there any other way I can insert it to get consistent results?

Comment: You can convert date to datetime by yourself but you will lose the time data as its noy being kept in database.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `DateField`, not a `DateTimeField`.

You need to use `DateTimeField` instead of `DateField`

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't alter values that are passed to fields: it sets them as attributes directly. So, your code:

```
>>> foo.value = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-10-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

sets the attribute `value` value to the return value of that function call, which is a `datetime.datetime` instance.

When you fetch it back from the database, it sets the value to whatever the database is giving you: in this case your field is a `DateField()`, so the database connector gives you a `datetime.date` instance.

It's not inconsistent: the database will always give you back a date, not a datetime. Even if you passed it a string instead: `2017-10-11`, you'd still get a date back.

The database itself is doing the coercion from string/datetime/whatever to whatever data type the column is.

Comment: Interestingly, you _used_ to be able to get fields to convert their values upon assigning to an attribute, but that went away with maybe Django 1.11 or even 1.8.